# Default value of textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

How to set value of textbox?

I have this 1 textbox, and i want to set the default value is 0 so that when user not entering anythng my calculation still can.

Comment: its faster to read the manual (msdn) or get the SDK first with samples because this is the first of your next 1000 questions... that maybe most solved there.

Comment: ...and yet people end up here nevertheless.

Comment: To be fair it doesn't always appear in the autocomplete of asp:TextBox so it's not super obvious http://i.imgur.com/roCFOzg.png

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can either be done in the markup (.aspx) like:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" Text="0" />
```

Or in the code-behind (.aspx.cs):

```
txt.Text = 0;
```

Or if you're using VB.NET:

```
txt.Text = 0
```

---

However, if you're doing a calculation based on this, you shouldn't rely on there always being a value in the textbox.

You could do:

```
Dim txtValue as Integer = 0
If IsNumeric(txt.Text) Then
   txtValue = txt.Text
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it with numbers, then you can tell the textbox that it should be with numbers, then "0" will be default.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TB_Numbers" TextMode="Number" Text="0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Curt mentioned, you can put default value directly in asp control or in code behind however if you don't wish to show a 0 in textbox always then once you call the calculation method you can do something like this.

```
short valueForTextBox1;
if(txt.Text == String.Empty)
{
txt.Text = 0;
valueForTextBox1 = 0;
}
else
{
if(Int16.TryParse(txt.Text, out valueForTextBox1))
{
//Do Calculation
}
else
{
//Show some error that user has entered invalid value.
}
}
```

This will help the user understand that they left some boxes empty when a zero will appear in them as calculation is called. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Converting a String into a Number** - in your case the value available in textbox.

```
var val1 = Number(document.getElementById("TextBox1").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this on the line of the textbox control to populate your date and time and make not visible if you want

```
Value='<%# Now()%>'
```