# how can I set a default value to zero if nothing is entered into the textbox

Tags: vb.net

how can I set a default value to zero if nothing is entered into the textbox?

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    TextBox1.Text = 0
End If
If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
    TextBox2.Text = 0
End If
```

Comment: Just follow this link you'll get your ans [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410611/default-value-of-textbox][1]

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set the `.Text` property of a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` to a value of 0 because it is a `String` value type. You can however set it to the string  representation of `0` which is `"0"`.

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
    Dim txtBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) Then txtBox.Text = CStr(0)
End Sub
```

If you were to set `Option Strict On`, then you would get an error when trying to set the `.Text` property to an integer.

Comment: Then use the backspace key or the delete key to remove it. Your question only specified that you wanted the value to be 0 if the original value was an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your context or what you're trying to but you could try something like this on your Save/Capture/Next or whatever button.

```
If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" Then MyIntegerVariable = 0
```