# how to fill the editable textbox value to 0 using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one textbox and it is not  readonly..
but by default it has to get filled by 0..
then depending on user requirement, textbox value may be altered...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: is the variable of type `int`?

Comment: Just check to see if what ever domain model object property you are using to populate the textbox contains a value. if not then default it to 0.

Comment: MyTextBox.Text = "0";
Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

A question like this was already solved. I personally would do it in the markup: Text="0". Linked the other question below.

[Default value of textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410611/default-value-of-textbox)

Answer (score -1):

"Placeholder" property will do the job:
Try the following: This works well with all latest browsers

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" placeholder="0">
</asp:TextBox>
```